# Can I delete duplicates 6.0 iOS DeviceSupport?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, xcode4

Why do I get duplicates of iOS 6.0 Device Support? And can I delete someone?
[image]

Comment: What duplicates? Each one of those is different.

Comment: Is it for different devices like the iPhone and iPad?

Comment: Every time you connect an iOS device to your computer while Xcode is running, if the device has a version of iOS not seen before by Xcode, it downloads various data such as debug symbols. This data is used to symbolicate crash reports, among other things. Each one you show is a different version of iOS. You can delete old ones like the one for 4.3.3 if you don't have such a device anymore and you won't ever need to symbolicate crash reports from devices with iOS 4.3.3. Some of the 6.0 ones may be from the beta.

Comment: @rmaddy: This should be an answer. :P

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You get duplicates of these because (as you guessed) they are for different combinations of hardware and software.

These are used to symbolicate the system symbols in crash reports from your devices or customer devices in the field.

It is safe to delete the versions you are not supporting and will not get crash reports from the field.

There is usually an iOS DeviceSupport folder in the Xcode.app bundle and somewhere in the user's Library folder.  When you connect a new device to your Mac, the symbol files from it are placed in the user's Library subfolders.  (~/Library/Developer/Xcode/"iOS DeviceSupport").

You can always copy these folders to an external drive if you do not feel comfortable just deleting them.

Comment: I owe you one, just saved 20+ GB's of space. Thanks a bunch